# Correct placement of style variable in React class component

Tags: css, reactjs, styles

Could someone please comment on the difference in React between putting style variables:

- outside of a class component function, but in the component script, versus
- in the body of the component, but outside the return statement, versus
- in the return statement, but outside of the render function, versus
- in the render function

Each of those will work, but I have no sense of why one might be preferable to another.

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    putStyleHere = { color: '#eee' }
    render() {
        const orPutStyleHere2 = { color: '#eee' }
        return (
            const orPutStyleHere3 = { color: '#eee' }
            <p style={putStyleHere}>Hello, world!</p>
        )
    }
}
const orPutStyleHere4 = { color: '#eee' }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Its best to have constants outside the render function so that they are not being re-declared/re-assigned on every render [As long as the const value is not going to change which seems like the case in your scenario]